# Selecting rows without key column

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to select matching records that have mismatched/corrupt key columns (ID) by using concat.

The below gives me an error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'samdb.songlist.album' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT 
    tmpsonglist.xfade
FROM
    tmpsonglist
WHERE
    (concat_ws('',tmpsonglist.album, tmpsonglist.genre) = concat_ws('',songlist.album, songlist.genre))
```

`samdb.songlist.album` does indeed exist, and I know the query works using `WHERE tmpsonglist.ID = songlist.ID`.

Can I use concat this way? Or do I need to have a key column to make this match?

Edit:

I have updated my attempt with the alias included, but still get the error `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'songlist' for update in FROM clause`

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE samdb.songlist 
SET 
    songlist.xfade = (SELECT 
            t.xfade
        FROM
            tmpsonglist AS t,
            songlist AS s
        WHERE
            t.album = s.album
                AND filename LIKE '%201501.mp3');
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: It does not exist as far as this query is concerned.  The table alias is not defined in the `from` clause, so `songlist` is not recognized.

Comment: Ah OK, I had wondered if I needed an alias, but it wasn't in the error. Alias' are new to me:) Also how come using the ID columns produces a good result normally?

Comment: ID fields usually work best because a) they usually have a key or primary key on them, and b) when joining on them, the key can be used.  When you join on an expression like you are doing in your question (using concat_ws), and not just a field, a key cannot be used, making the query much slower.

Comment: Speed isn't a concern at this point. I'm just recovering from a backup for a few records. This select is part of a bigger query which will update some field data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, could you please elaborate about the alias? Perhaps submit an answer. It would be really helpful:)

Comment: I updated my question with a better attempt

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the query you want is:

```
UPDATE samdb.songlist s
    SET s.xfade = (SELECT t.xfade
                   FROM tmpsonglist t
                   WHERE t.album = s.album AND filename LIKE '%201501.mp3'
                  );
```

Note that if there is no match, `xfade` will be set to `NULL` with your logic.